# Transit Visa for Kuwait Airport Self-Transfer Without Luggage for Indians?

Tags: indian-citizens, kuwait, self-transfer

I am an Indian passport holder. I have a flight from Rome to Kuwait (WizzAir) and then Kuwait to Chennai (AirIndia) with a layover of 5-6 hours. Both the legs were booked as separate tickets with separate airlines and PNRs. I don't have any check-in bags and just my hand luggage with me. Do I need a visa to move from my WizzAir flight to the AirIndia one?

I don't have to (or intend to) even get to the baggage collection area.

Comment: Your problem might be that WizzAir may consider Kuwait to be your final destination, so to be allowed to board you would need documentation for entry to Kuwait, regardless.

Answer (score 5):

> Do I need a visa to move from my WizzAir flight to the AirIndia one?

Yes

> I don't have to (or intend to) even get to the baggage collection area.

Doesn't matter. Whizz Air sold you a ticket from Rome to Kuwait. What yo do in Kuwait isn't their concern and the fact that you have a same day departure ticket is irrelevant to them. They will need to verify that you can enter your destination and they won't allow you to board if you don't have proper entry documentation for Kuwait.

There are rare exceptions to this rule but they almost always require good-will from the check in agent and you can't rely on that, even if your case is one of those exceptions.

Comment: Very valid point that. Would it solve my problem if I were to book a connection out from Kuwait to Abu Dhabi (where I have a visa on arrival option) also with Wizz Air? Would that allow them to board me through to Abu Dhabi?

Comment: It would if Wizz Air would actually sell connecting flights, which they unfortunately don't.  See https://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/wizz-services/mix-match-flights

Answer (score 1):

I actually live in Kuwait, and here, when you exit the flight and enter the airport, you can simply walk to the other waiting area of the next flight. So, supposing you do get on the flight, there is no problem.

However, but you go on the flight, you maybe asked at the country where you get your boarding pass if you have the required documents for Kuwait. Perhaps the best option would be to mail them before hand and ask?